# How CreateReadStream With URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios, openai-api

I'm trying to get a variant of the image (URL), with OpenAI but fs.CreateReadStream() doesn't work for this, any solutions?

The OpenAI documentation uses fs.createReadStream, although I've tried http.get, Axios.get and neither works :(

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai')
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: 'KEY',
})

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)
const fs = require("node:fs")

async function getVariant() {

    const A = await openai.createImageVariation(
        fs.createReadStream("https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/778761434992476230/691f620e3c0b1ea006c9fabd7a07d485.png"),
         1,
         "1024x1024");


    console.log(`${A.data.data[0].url} \n`)
        
}

getVariant()
```

I've tried http.get, Axios.get , Fetch , Buffer.  for get a Image Variant With OpenAI but neither works :(